# Issue with ExpressJS and post timeout

Tags: node.js, apache, express

I get an issue with `ExpressJS`. I get an error message when uploading large files...

**Error message :**

```
Bad Gateway
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at xxxxxxxxx Port 80
```

Everything works when the connexion of the user is above 3G...

Is there any configuration to do on my `Apache` or about `ExpressJS` options ?

**Edit #1 :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the reason is a timeout happening on express server. Try increasing the timeout for the express connections.

```
const server = app.listen(8080);
server.timeout = 300000; // 5min = 5*60*1000
```

Comment: I got the same error message with the increasing timeout.

Comment: I got the same error message with the increasing timeout. See edit to see my test... I used `Slow 3G` because I have a user with a bad connexion.